# Creating a set of sub-sets of size K  from a given  interval- using Set In Java

Tags: java

I'd love your help with this following problem:

I want to write in Java a method that will gets three values: first, last and K, so and creates all the sub-sets of size L of numbers within the bounded interval [first,last],

For example: If first=1, last=3 and K=2, so the result will be {1,2},{1,3},{2,3}.

Ok, So I decided that the result value of the function will be `Set<Set<Integer>>` , But I'm not sure of how exactly I need to do that, What is the algorithm and the right way to write it.

```
public static Set<Set<Integer>> generateKsubsets( 
int first, int last, int K){
Set<Set<Integer>> result = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
```

question 1: Is this the right Implemention of set to use in this case? 
To be honest, I'm not sure why do I use it here. Can I use here HasgTree? Is there any difference between theme in this case?

```
If(K==0) {
```

question 2:
   So here I would Like to return an empty set of the type that I defined,
 How should I do that?Can 
I add an empty set into the result set?

```
return result;
}
```

And now the main question(3): I can't understand how my algorithm should work and how should I write it using this set.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like homework (if it is, please tag it as such), so I'll only give a few hints:

1. `HashSet` should do the job. However, note that in order for `HashSet` to work like a mathematical set (i.e. it cannot contain multiple occurrences of the same element), the element type (in this case, `Set<Integer>`) must have `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations that tell the `HashSet` when two elements are equal. Most `Set` implementations do not have these methods implemented the way you'd expect, but you probably don't need it here. Just remember to not add the same set several times.
2. `new HashSet<Set<Integer>>()` *is* an empty set. If you add a set to it, it is no longer empty.
3. A set can be considered to be a binary number. If your range is 2-5, the elements you can select from are `{2, 3, 4, 5}`. Any subset of this set can be represented as a binary number with four digits, each digit corresponding to an element in the main set, and being 1 if the element is in the subset, and 0 if it is not. So the subset `{3, 5}` is `0101` (2 is absent, 3 is present, 4 is absent, 5 is present), and `{2, 3, 4}` is `1110`. So if you can find a way of creating all binary numbers with the correct number of digits, and how to create a subset based on each number, you have your algorithm.